# Php doesn't read specific directory?

Tags: php, centos

Something strange happens with my centos server. I have an asterisk server and I need to access to the recording dir. But it is impossible.

The dir /var/spool is unreadable. I can access with ssh with root and apache users, but from php it is impossible.

I don't know why!! This dir and /var/test/ has the same permissions (owner, group, chmod 755, ALL).

I use this php code:

I try to use exec function (works from another dirs), is_readable, file_get_contents but nothing :(

```
function wav_callid($id) {
        $id = (int) $id;
        $filename = 'cid'.$id.'.wav';
        $path = '/var/spool/asterisk/monitor/' . $filename;
        $tmp_path = '/tmp/' . $this->global_model->generate_random_hash();
        exec("cp '$path' '$tmp_path'");
        var_dump(is_readable('/var/spool')); // RETURN FALSE
        var_dump(scandir('/var/spool')); // RETURN FALSE
        var_dump(file_get_contents($path)); // RETURN FALSE

        var_dump(is_readable('/var/test')); // RETURN TRUE
        var_dump(scandir('/var/test')); // RETURN ARRAY

        /*header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
        header('Content-Type: audio/x-wav');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . $filename);
        header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
        header('Expires: 0');
        header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
        header('Pragma: public');
        echo file_get_contents($tmp_path);*/

    }
```

What do I have to do?

Sorry for my bad english.

Thanks

Comment: check if apache has rights to read this folder

Comment: apache user has rights because i enter to this user with ssh and opens the dir.

Comment: if is_readable function returns false - it hasn't rights on read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Selinux was blocking this dir.

Command for Centos 6:

```
 echo 0 >/selinux/enforce
```

And reboot.

Answer (score 0):

Save your project into /var/www/html directory.Then change permission.Or create project foldar symbolic link into /var/www/html directory.